# Sum of series involving binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Evaluate the following;

$$\sum_{r=0}^{50} (r+1) ^{1000-r}C_{50-r}$$

Using $^{n}C_{r}=^{n}C_{n-r}$ we get $\sum_{r=0}^{50} (r+1) ^{1000-r}C_{950}$

but I am not getting how to solve $\sum_{r=0}^{50} r \cdot \hspace{0.5 mm} ^{1000-r}C_{950}$

Comment: do you mean $\binom{1000-r}{50-r}$?  Also, you can do $\binom{n}{k}$ via `\binom{n}{k}`.

Comment: @Mark Yeah I mean $\binom {100-r}{50-r}$

Comment: If it is $100$ and not $1000$, them please edit the question.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat It is 1000 only

Comment: Actually you wrote 100 in the previous comment ...

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle  \sum^{50}_{r=0}r\cdot \binom{1000-r}{950}=0\cdot \binom{1000}{950}+1\cdot \binom{999}{950}+2\cdot \binom{998}{950}+\cdots \cdots \cdots +50\cdot \binom{950}{950}$

Using $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} = $ Coefficients of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^n$

so  coefficients of 
$\displaystyle x^{950}$ in

$\displaystyle 1\cdot (1+x)^{999}+2\cdot (1+x)^{998}+3\cdot (1+x)^{997}+\cdots \cdots +50 \cdot (1+x)^{950}$

let $S=1\cdot (1+x)^{999}+2\cdot (1+x)^{998}+3\cdot (1+x)^{997}+\cdots \cdots +50 \cdot (1+x)^{950}\cdots \cdots (\star)$

multiply both side by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x}$

$\displaystyle S\cdot \frac{1}{1+x}=1\cdot (1+x)^{998}+2\cdot (1+x)^{997}+\cdots+49 \cdot (1+x)^{949}+50\cdot (1+x)^{949}\cdots \cdots (\star \star)$

So $\displaystyle \bigg(1-\frac{1}{1+x}\bigg) = (1+x)^{999}+(1+x)^{998}+\cdots \cdots (1+x)^{949}-50(1+x)^{949}$

So $\displaystyle S \cdot \frac{x}{1+x} = \frac{(1+x)^{1000}-(1+x)^{950}}{1+x-1}-50(1+x)^{949}$

So $\displaystyle S = \frac{(1+x)^{1001}-(1+x)^{951}}{x^2}-\frac{50(1+x)^{950}}{x}$

So coefficients of $x^{950}$ in $\displaystyle  \frac{(1+x)^{1001}-(1+x)^{951}}{x^2}-$ coefficient of $x^{950}$ in $\displaystyle \frac{50(1+x)^{950}}{x}$

So coefficients of $x^{952}$ in $\bigg((1+x)^{1001}-(1+x)^{951}\bigg)-$ coefficients of $x^{951}$ in $(1+x)^{950}$

So we are getting $\displaystyle = \binom{1001}{952}$

Answer (score 2):

Set $50-r=u$
$$\sum_{u=0}^{50}(51-u)\binom{950+u}{950}=\sum_{u=0}^{50}\{1002-(951+u)\}\binom{950+u}{950}$$

$$=1002\sum_{u=0}^{50}\binom{950+u}{950}-951\sum_{u=0}^{50}\binom{951+u}{951}$$

Now $\displaystyle\sum_{u=0}^{50}\binom{950+u}{950}$  is the coefficient of $x^{950}$ in $$\displaystyle\sum_{u=0}^{50}(1+x)^{950+u}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a hockey stick made of hockey sticks. Expand each term $(r+1)\binom{1000-r}{950}$ into a column of $r+1$ copies of $\binom{1000-r}{950}$, then add up the rows using the hockey stick identity, then add up the rows sums using the hockey stick identity.
$$\begin{array}{rrrcrl}
\displaystyle\binom{1000}{950}&+\displaystyle2\binom{999}{950}&+\displaystyle3\binom{999}{950}&\dots&+\displaystyle50\binom{950}{950}\\\hline\\
=\displaystyle\binom{1000}{950}&+\displaystyle\binom{999}{950}&+\displaystyle\binom{999}{950}&\dots&+\displaystyle\binom{950}{950} &\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}=\displaystyle\binom{1001}{951}
\\\\ & +\displaystyle\binom{999}{950}&+\displaystyle\binom{998}{950}&\dots &+\displaystyle\binom{950}{950}
&\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}=+\displaystyle\binom{1000}{951}
\\\\ &&+\displaystyle\binom{998}{950}&\dots &+\displaystyle\binom{950}{950}
&\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}=+\displaystyle\binom{999}{951}
\\\\&&&\ddots&\vdots\;\;\;\;&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\vdots
\\\\&&&&+\displaystyle\binom{950}{950}&\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}=+\displaystyle\binom{951}{951}
\\\\
&&&&&\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}=\displaystyle\boxed{\binom{1002}{952}}
\end{array}$$